# sudo apt install python3-dev for windows

Tags: django, django-oscar

I'm trying django-oscars demo and I'm wanted to test it out but I'm literally stuck on the first part lol. I need help since I can't use sudo for windows what should I do then? "sudo apt install python3-dev"  [djang-oscar](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/internals/sandbox.html)

Comment: I think it's only configured to run in Linux, you can try to run it on [wsl]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: See https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/platform_database_support.html?highlight=windows#operating-system - it's going to be very difficult to get it running on Windows.